# Why after appending images from a directory to a np.array the shape of the array is bigger than sum of shape of images?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to load a bunch of images from a directory and append them in an array. After loading all the images when I try to reshape the array, the shape of the appended array is slightly bigger than the 'num of images x the shape of the image(flattened)'. for example, when I load 647 images with the shape of 61x61x3, the amended array has the shape of 7222462 which is slightly bigger than 647x61x61x3.

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
image_count = 0
images = np.array
I = np.array
for filename in glob.glob('/Users/images/*.jpg'): 
    im = Image.open(filename)
    I = np.array(im.getdata())
    image_count += 1
    images = np.append(images,I)

images.reshape(-1,image_count)
images.shape
```

I also tried to concatenate, but I had the same problem.

```
 images = np.concatenate((images,I), axis = None)
```

Comment: You seem to start by making `images` a function at the line `images = np.array` so you'll end up with a function and a load of arrays appended.

Comment: Read the `np.append` docs before using.  Do not treat it like a list append clone.  And test with a small example where you check more than the resulting shape.

Comment: We recommend appending the arrays to a list, and using just one `np.array` at the end.  It's faster and easier to get right.

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj, I ended up using your method and it works!


'
`image_count = 0
images = []

for filename in glob.glob('/Users/images/*.jpg'): 
    while image_count < 2:
        im = np.array(Image.open(filename))
        image_count += 1
        iamages = images.append(im.tolist())

images = np.array(images)
images.reshape(-1,image_count)
images.shape
`